# Angular 6 htaccess configuration for HTTPS website

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, https

I have just installed an SSL certificate on my website, but after that the refresh function on my application is broken and return always **404 Error: Not found**
I changed my **.htaccess** file but always the same problem.

Here is my **.htaccess** file before upgrading my website to HTTPS (it was working)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|json|css)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 10 Apr 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 404 /dist/
```

And after upgrading to HTTPS I change it to this (not working)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|json|css)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                FileETag None
                Header unset ETag
                Header unset Pragma
                Header unset Cache-Control
                Header unset Last-Modified
                Header set Pragma "no-cache"
                Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
                Header set Expires "Mon, 10 Apr 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
        </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 404 /dist/
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it was an issue on the apache configuration file.

When I was using the HTTP protocole the **virtualHost:80** contains the option `AllowOverride All`
But in the **virtualHost:443** it doesn't contain this option, so after I add it to this virtualHost, it works fine with the first version of the **.htaccess** file (see my question).

I put this here for people having the same issue.